# Markov processes with higher order functions in R

Tags: r, functional-programming, higher-order-functions, sapply, markov

I'm looking for a clean way to run simulations where each iteration depends on the result of the preceding iteration in a "functional style." For example, say we want to take a normally distributed sample of size 10 with mean `meanInit`, take the mean of our sample and use that to generate another sample, and repeat the process. Using `Reduce`, we can perform 100 iterations:

```
meanInit = 0
nextStep <- function(param, step) mean(rnorm(10, param))
Reduce(nextStep, 1:100, meanInit, accumulate = T)
```

However, this feels a bit abusive as our function `nextStep` isn't truly a binary operation; indeed, we ignore the second argument `step`. Is there an alternative method for performing a task that doesn't require us to "pretend" our function is a binary operation? I'm looking for a solution involving higher order functions. No `for` loops please.

Perhaps this  question is best stated in the form of an analogy:

**`sapply` is to `replicate` as `Reduce` is to ______?**

That is, if we wanted to, for example, take 100 random normal samples of size 10 and calculate the mean, we could (ab)use `sapply` with a function that ignores its argument as follows:

```
sapply(1:100, function(x) mean(rnorm(10)))
```

Or we could perform the same task cleanly (without writing a function that ignores its argument) using `replicate`:

```
replicate(100, mean(rnorm(10)))
```

I'm looking for an analogous relative of `Reduce`.

Comment: `for`? Be a rebel !

Comment: `Reduce`'s code is full of `for()` loops by the way - there's nothing inherently wrong with a loop.

Comment: I've generally found that any sort of sequential processing that involves dependencies on prior values using anything other than `cumsum` or `cumprod` will run better and be less error prone using `for`-loops.

Comment: @thelatemail didn't say there was! I just prefer reading/writing code that avoids for loops but I know many others who feel the opposite.

Comment: @42 You might be right, though maybe that wouldn't be the case if there were a function to fill in the blank in my analogy above?

Comment: I'd suggest looking for code that has been written for solving differential equations and especially the code involving stochastic differential equations.